# Cannot run deployed app [ .NET 7 RUNTIME ] on ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nano

Hey guys after deploying and moving app to server i get this error

```
-bash: ./WEBAPP: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Idk why, i am trying to use #!/.WEBAPP but this does not work to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. Problem was wrong Target Runtime. This is correct one:
[image]